# Android deeplinking Intent sspPattern issue

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have got two links for email confirmation and password reset, since email confirm link doesn't have a `pathPrefix` it conflicts with password reset link.

I used `sspPattern` to classify them by the differences they have but password link triggers both intent. Links are given below.

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.deepLink.ResetPassword"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/my_website">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="mywebsite.de"
                android:pathPrefix="/resetpassword"
                android:sspPattern="/resetpassword?userId=.*&amp;c=.*"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.deepLink.EmailConfirmation"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/my_website">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="mywebsite.de"
                android:sspPattern="//mywebsite.de/?userId=.*&amp;code=.*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**email confirm link**: https://mywebsite.de/resetpassword?UserId=35541&c=B66ZcFVwXfGhyHZQ==

**password reset link**: https://mywebsite.de/?userId=35541&code=S%2bvaKQjLJC

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:pathPrefix` for both links

For link: https://mywebsite.de/resetpassword?UserId=35541&c=B66ZcFVwXfGhyHZQ==

```
android:pathPrefix="/resetpassword"
```

For link: https://mywebsite.de/userId=35541&code=S%2bvaKQjLJC

```
android:pathPrefix="/userId"
```

Comment: The second link  is a query and there is a question mark "https://mywebsite.de/?userId= ... " hence i can not use android:pathPrefix="/userId". It doesn't get triggered then. thanks for your answer though